# Can one always construct an equivalent measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, finance

Assume that one has constructed a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, Q)$ and a cadlag process $X$ which follows some properties of interest, i.e martingale property.

Can one always construct an equivalent measure $P$?

The background and reason for my question: In various texts and articles I have seen that financial engineers construct a martingale process directly in the risk neutral world. They simply seem to assume that there exist an equivalent measure $P$ representing the physical world on which the process does not allow for arbitrage opportunities, and thus applying the fundamental theorem of asset pricing.

P.S: The process $X$ does not need to be of the same class in $P$ as in $Q$, it does not even have to still be a martingale with respect to $P$. As long as the process $X$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ does not allow for any arbitrage opportunities.

Comment: Isnt there a theorem saying that if the market is X and Y. Then the eq. measure exists?

Comment: @Olba12 I did not follow what you ment by "if the market is X and Y". Would you please eloborate this?

Comment: I don't fully remember but my best guess is X=free of arbitrage, and Y=complete.

Comment: @Olba12 A market is arbitrage free $\iff$ an equivalent measure $Q$ exists for which the discounted process is a $Q$-martingale. The completeness is implied by uniqueness of the equivalent measure $Q$.

Comment: Are you asking why it is often assumed that the real world measure $P$ is arbitrage free?

Comment: @JohnM No, some financial engineers seem to construct a process which is a martingale under some probability measure, say $Q$. They assume arbitrage free market in the physical world under measure $P$. Then they calibrate the process under $Q$ against a set of option prices. But the price of the options is given in the measure $Q$ only if it is equivalent to $P$. They seem to assume this without showing. So I wonder if  they assume that there will always exist atleast one equivalent measure $P$ for which the process will be arbitrage free. No constraints properties or on class of process in$Q$

Comment: It seems to be called implied calibration (not to be confused with implied volatility).

Comment: @JohnM Evidently, the process $Q$ is equivalent with itself. Do the existence rely on the fact that one always can choose $P=Q$? Is a market always arbitrage free if the process is a martingale in the physical world?

Comment: You are looking for the "Equivalen Martingale Measure (EMM)" .

Comment: @alexjo If one chooses that a process is a martingale in the physical world, then $P=Q$ would suffice to show that a EMM exists, no?

Comment: We don't start with $Q$ and construct $P$.  Rather, we make assumptions about $P$ and construct $Q$.  When calibrating the volatilities of prices processes, it might seem that we are calibrating $Q$, but what really is going on is that the assumptions about $P$ are being calibrated.

Comment: @JohnM So given a process, they assume the market is in such a way that no arbitrage can exist with the given process, then they simply state the discounted martingale process in $Q$?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a very harsh assumption that is not necessary valid?

Comment: That's right.  No arbitrage is assumed.  This assumption is not so strong:  In practice, arbitrage possibilities are small and quickly exploited.  So for modelling purposes assuming arbitrage free is not a big deal.  A more serious issue is usually market completeness.  In practice, usually markets are not complete.